# Change cell colour based on 2 other cell colours

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I need to create a VBA formula that will help me to automatically change the color of a cell, when I fill other 2 cells **manually** with other colors.

Here is an example:

[image]

As a result of manually filling in cells K and M, I need cell Q to be automatically filled in green in the first row.

The same for the second one: if I fill K with yellow + M with green, the result of Q must be that it is filled in green.

Is this possible? It would be enough for me if you could give me the example of the first two conditions to build the following ones myself.

Here's my code:

```
Sub RatingColor()
    If range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
     
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
     
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
     
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     ElseIf range("F13").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) And range("H13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
     range("J13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have create the color-formula and It works, but what I need now is the loop part and if possible, to apply this automatically everytime I change a color.

Comment: You will need to check the Interior.Color property of the first 2 cells - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color, so loop through the row(? or column? You need to show us the layout of the cells to give you more info) and check the first 2 cells' color and it's a matter of If/Else statement. Edit the post to show your code if you have any so that we can help you further. If M is a constant color (green) then you only need to check K to get the color for Q.

Comment: There is no a standard event able to be triggered by cell interior color change. But it is possible to create a class able too build it.

Comment: Use For loop to do the loop, it might be possible to use Worksheet_Change event to detect the change but I'm not sure if changing interior color is detectable by it. Unfortunately I'm off to bed now so try figure to this out by yourself if no one is answering, good luck!

Comment: Do you still need an event able to detect the cell interior color change? If yes, I have now some time and I can try building the necessary class and the necessary procedure to be called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the permutation you have given in your post, put this in the Worksheet module that you want this code to run, take note that it will actually trigger on every change you made on the worksheet, not just when you change a color:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim colorGreen As Long
        Dim colorYellow As Long
        Dim colorOrange As Long
        Dim colorRed As Long
        Dim i As Long
        
        Const rowStart As Long = 2 'first row, change to your purpose
        Const rowEnd As Long = 20 'last row, change to your purpose
        
        'Define color to variables
        colorGreen = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        colorYellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        colorOrange = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        colorRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        
        With Sheet1 'change to correct worksheet reference
            For i = rowStart To rowEnd
                Select Case .Cells(i, 6).Interior.color 'Check cell color in Column F
                    Case colorGreen
                        Select Case .Cells(i, 8).Interior.color 'Check cell color in column H
                            Case colorGreen, colorYellow, colorOrange, colorRed: .Cells(i, 10).Interior.color = .Cells(i, 8).Interior.color
                        End Select
                    Case colorYellow
                        Select Case .Cells(i, 8).Interior.color 'Check cell color in column H
                            Case colorGreen, colorYellow, colorOrange
                                .Cells(i, 10).Interior.color = .Cells(i, 8).Interior.color
                        End Select
                    Case colorOrange
                        Select Case .Cells(i, 8).Interior.color 'Check cell color in column H
                            Case colorGreen
                                .Cells(i, 10).Interior.color = colorYellow
                            Case colorYellow
                                .Cells(i, 10).Interior.color = colorOrange
                            Case colorOrange
                                .Cells(i, 10).Interior.color = colorRed
                        End Select
                End Select
            Next i
        End With
End Sub
```

[image]